# Authorizing google API error

Tags: android, api

I'm trying to Authorizing and using googel API for android but when I try to configure build dependencies and sync the project it give me an error like

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.> Dependency Error.`

See console for details.

[image: screenshot for the error]

build gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'

compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'

compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think your google apis are conflicting

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
```

Might internally be using other dependencies, with different versions.

Try running: `/gradlew app:dependencies` to see all your dependencies